# Action only visible in form view, need it in tree view too

Tags: action, odoo, wizard, openerp-7

I have a custom module I am trying to port from openERP 6.1 to openERP 7.

In this module I have defined several new actions that point to wizards in the product.product model.
In openERP 6.1 these action links appear in the sidebar in the product tree view, allowing me to use a selection of products, and in the form view, using only the currently shown product.

However, in openERP 7 my action links appear under the "More" button only in the form view, not in the tree view. Since I need to be able to use my actions on multiple products at once, this is a problem.

Here is my action definition:

```
<act_window id="action_my_id"
            name="my name"
            res_model="my_model.function"
            src_model="product.product"
            view_mode="form" target="new" view_type="form" />
```

How do I make this and my other actions show under the "More" button in tree view as well as form view?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer [here](https://www.odoo.com/forum/Help-1/question/How-to-add-submenu-to-More-button-on-form-view-17410) on the odoo forum:

In order for an act_window action to be visible in tree view, you need to add the following attribute to it:

```
key2="client_action_multi"
```

So now the action definition looks like this:

```
<act_window id="action_my_id"
        name="my name"
        res_model="my_model.function"
        src_model="product.product"
        key2="client_action_multi"
        view_mode="form" target="new" view_type="form" />
```